# Prevent element stretching with implicit width and no whitespace wrap

Tags: html, css, implicit, stretch, nowrap

I have an HTML page with a couple of divs inside each other:

```
div#given                -- display: block
    div#one              -- display: table
        div#two          -- display: table-row
            div#three    -- display: block
                div#four -- display: block
```

`#given` is given by a third party and has an explicit `width` set, but that width can change via JavaScript.

`#one`, `#two`, `#three` and `#four` all have implicit widths.

`#three` has a stylesheet like:

```
#three
{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
#three:hover
{
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

`#four` contains a lot of text and totally overflows `#three`, but the overflow is hidden until `#three` is hovered.
Now to `#four` I want to apply `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, but that only seems to work when `white-space: nowrap;` is set as well. However, that stretches both `#three` and `#four` a couple of thousand pixels to the left, which is absolutely not what I want.
So far I have found no other solution that explicitly setting a width for `#four`, which is (possible, but very) very impractical since the width of `#given` is not fixed.

Is there any non-JS way to do this?

Here's my problem in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zquL7sem/3/

My goal is to have the area inside the red border end at the blue line and display three dots where the texts ends, without setting an explicit width for `#three` or `#four`.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use the `display:table` propertie element will expand as much as content requires such as a real table does.
you can fix this with : `table-layout:fixed` and `width`.
https://jsfiddle.net/zquL7sem/4/